# Bootstrap 5 fixed-bottom footer covering content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, footer, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to do a fixed footer using fixed-bottom with react & bootstrap, the problem is that it covers some content, already tried some things but none worked, how can I fix? ( Code and Demo below )

Footer code:

```js
            <MDBFooter bgColor='light' className='text-center text-lg-start text-muted mt-auto fixed-bottom'>
                <section className='d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-center p-2 border-bottom'>
                    <div className='me-5'>
                        <span>Siga nas redes sociais</span>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <a href='' className='me-4 text-reset'>
                            <i className='fab fa-facebook-f'></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href='' className='me-4 text-reset'>
                            <i className='fab fa-twitter'></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href='' className='me-4 text-reset'>
                            <i className='fab fa-instagram'></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <div className='container text-center text-md-start mt-2'>
                        <div className='row mt-3'>
                            <div className='col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4'>
                                <h6 className='text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4'>
                                    <i className='fas fa-gem me-3'></i>Lorem Ipsum
                                </h6>
                                <p>
                                    Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4'>
                                <h6 className='text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4'>Contato</h6>
                                <p>
                                    <i className='fas fa-envelope me-3'></i>
                                    info@example.com
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <i className='fas fa-phone me-3'></i> + 01 234 567 88
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <div className='text-center p-4' style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)' }}>
                    © 2022 Copyright:
                    <a className='text-reset fw-bold' href='https://mdbootstrap.com/'>
                        lorem.com
                    </a>
                </div>
            </MDBFooter>
```

Demo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHrVx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem using min-height property on the page content.

Answer (score 0):

We check 320px as the smallest mobile screen available these days. below that level is not necessary for today's devices. I could see you are checking the page on 280px.

I doubt that you added any sticky property to the footer? - If yes please remove that on that level.

Comment: Well, I just tested it on 320>px resolution and it causes the same problem as You can see thereon the imgur link i'll send
Btw it can just cause some problems because of the hamburger on the page that expands.   https://imgur.com/xJLEPFx

Comment: Suggestion: Add a different color to the menu dropdown, so the user could easily see the separation.

I doubt what exactly the issue is here, is it related to the header or footer.

Comment: Footer position is fixed, it should being not in there so its not covered, what i would like to have is a footer who is exactly on bottom doesnt matter the page height but not covering things like is doing with the dropdown like in the imgur im going to show https://imgur.com/oAtc9CY @Stephen

Comment: I prefer to remove the sticky property of the footer from the mobile screen. use it only on large screens such as tablets and desktops.

Please consider this as a suggestion.

Comment: this makes sense and looks like a great thing to do, thanks for helping me!

Comment: sorry mentioning you again but I was testing your suggestion with breakpoints again and noticed that the dropdown wasn't really the problem and yes the footer is covering all content, not only the dropdown, I will post an imgur below, the problem with this is that if I want to solve this totally I would want to set smaller resolutions and that would cause problems to the footer to render totally on bottom. imgur.com/x8xhcDE @Stephen

Comment: Please check, am I replicating your issue here?
https://jsfiddle.net/Stephen2hats/q20ps1fh/1/

Comment: sorry for taking to long, but I think you are.

Comment: the real problem is that I just want to the footer to stay at the end of the page if theres enough space to him to be not, and not to always be shown like as sticky one.